# Noe4j: height of a root node

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I'm using Neo4j 3.5 version

I want to figure out the height of a node **'p'** in the relationship `(p:Person)-[r:CHILD*0..]->(c:Person)`.

Height of a node is defined as the distance between the root and the leaf node which is at the maximum distance from the root.

I want to figure it out for the > 100 000 nodes using apoc procedures. Could anyone please suggest how should I solve this problem.

Comment: Your question needs clarification. Is p the root?  is c the leaf? 

or are you meaning something like this? 

    MATCH (root:Person)-[:CHILD*0..]->(p:Person)-[:CHILD*0..]->(leaf:Person)
    WHERE NOT  (
                           (:Person)-[:CHILD]->(root)  
                           OR
                           (leaf)-[:CHILD]->(:Person)
                     )

Comment: @Graphileon Yes, I meant the same. p is the root and c is the leaf, which could be some relationships distance away from the root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out:

```
MATCH k = (p:Person)-[r:CHILD*0..]->(c:Person) 
where p.name = "Krishna"
with p, collect(length(k)) as score
unwind score as e
return p.code, max(e) as score
```

Here,

**k** is the length of the each path

**collect(length(k))** makes a list of lengths of paths to child nodes against each root

**unwind** will be used to traverse each element of the list

And then using `max` function we can figure out the farthest child node distance

Answer (score 0):

The following is probably the most straightforward query. It ensures that the last node of each matched path is a leaf node, and then returns the path's length. APOC is not needed.

```
MATCH k = (p:Person)-[:CHILD*0..]->(c)
WHERE NOT (c)-[:CHILD]->()
RETURN p.code, LENGTH(k) AS score
```

*I assume that the `CHILD` relationship always points to a `Person`, and so for efficiency I leave that label out of the end nodes in the above query.*

[UPDATE]

If you only want the path with the maximum path length, you can do this:

```
MATCH k = (p:Person)-[:CHILD*0..]->(c)
WHERE NOT (c)-[:CHILD]->()
RETURN p.code, LENGTH(k) AS score
ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: this will return multiple results for the same node. if a root has paths to 4 leaf nodes, then it will result in 4 paths and 4 results. So this would give the right answer. For each root node, it should return only one result

Comment: If there are 4 paths, there are obviously 4 path lengths. Are you looking for the maximum length? Your question did not state that.

Comment: We have to achieve the same for > 100,000 nodes. Querying for each node is not an efficient solution. Instead, I would go for batching. And this query will not give correct results for the batched query. This will work only if we are finding it for a single node.

Comment: Finding the longest path from a given node is known to be expensive in large DBs. Batching *sounds* attractive, but may be difficult to actually implement since it may not be easy come up with non-overlapping searches. See [here](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/achieving-longestpath-using-cypher/) for some suggestions.